# Pade Approximation of dead time

Tags: matlab, approximation, step-response

For the time delay $e^{-sT}$ I shall find the Pade Approximation for $M = 0$ and $N = 1$.

$f(s) = \sum_i^{\infty} a_is^i \approx \dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^{N} b_is^i}{\sum_{m=0}^{M} c_is^i}$

$e^{-sT} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-sT)^i}{i!}$

Using the Taylor approximation for $e^{-sT}$ I yield

$1 -sT \approx \frac{P_N(s)}{Q_M(s)}$

$1 -sT \approx \frac{b_0 + b_1 s}{c_0}$

with $c_0 = 1$ per definition according to my materials.

This leads me to

$1 -sT \approx b_0 + b_1 s$

$b_0 = 1$

$b_1 = -T$

If I now want to check the step response of $e^{-sT}$ and my approximation MATLAB complains about my function having more zeroes than poles, which is not surprising as I thought I would get my transfer function from $G(s) = \frac{P_N(s)}{Q_M(s)}$.

I'm sure there is a basic misunderstanding of what I am doing here on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no misunderstanding at all. The Padé approximant you found is correct.

The "problem" is that you chose $M$ and $N$ such that the transfer function you get to approximate the delay is *improper*. Namely, the order of the numerator exceeds the order of the denominator.

In Control Theory, improper systems are not too useful because they cannot be realized in real life. A transfer function with more zeros than poles contains pure differentiators, so the transfer function represents a system that is non-causal (assuming stability, as Matt pointed out in the comments below), and non-causal systems cannot be physically realized.

Comment: Just a remark: systems with an improper transfer function can be causal, but not causal and stable at the same time. See my answer for a possible causal step response.

Comment: @MattL. I tend to (mistakenly) ignore unstable systems, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's all a bit (?) theoretical, I admit.

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [Tendero's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46448/4298) everything you've calculated is correct. Matlab is supposed to complain because the system with transfer function

$$H(s)=1-sT\tag{1}$$

has (assuming causality) a step response

$$a(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1-sT}{s}\right\}=u(t)-T\delta(t)\tag{2}$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta impulse. The system is unstable and its step response is unbounded/ill-defined at $t=0$.

Comment: This system is unstable for both causal and noncausal cased, right? That impulse would appear no matter what. Are there any examples where a system can be either causal and unstable OR noncausal and stable, depending on the ROC?

Comment: @Tendero: Yes (to your first question). Examples of causal and unstable, or non-causal and stable systems are easy to find: just put a pole in the right half-plane and you'll have a causal unstable system or a non-causal stable system, e.g. $H(s)=1/(s-1)$

Comment: There's something that is not clear to me. Sorry if this question is kind of silly. But given for example the transfer function $H(s)=s^2/(s+1)$, one can find a ROC such that the system is both causal and stable. However, the transfer function is improper. As far as I understand from your comment in my answer above, this is not possible. So where am I making the mistake?